# Laravel : Make MySQL row as column in the html table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is the structure of `MySQL` table.

[image]

This is the sample data.

[image]

What is the best way in order to make this kind of report?

[image]

This is my working code so far.

```php
function get_enrollment()
    {
        $sel_year = Input::get('sel_year');
        $school_id = Input::get('school_id');
        $return = "";
        $return .= "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>";
        $return .= "<tr>
                <th rowspan='2'>Level</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Quater 1</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Quater 2</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Quater 3</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Quater 4</th>
            </tr>";
        $return .= "<tr>
                <th>Male</th>
                <th>Female</th>
                <th>Male</th>
                <th>Female</th>
                <th>Male</th>
                <th>Female</th>
                <th>Male</th>
                <th>Female</th>
            </tr>";

        $male_q1_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 1, 'gender' => 1,'level'=>1])->first();
        $female_q1_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 1, 'gender' => 0,'level'=>1])->first();
        $male_q2_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 2, 'gender' => 1,'level'=>1])->first();
        $female_q2_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 2, 'gender' => 0,'level'=>1])->first();
        $male_q3_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 3, 'gender' => 1,'level'=>1])->first();
        $female_q3_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 3, 'gender' => 0,'level'=>1])->first();
        $male_q4_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 4, 'gender' => 1,'level'=>1])->first();
        $female_q4_level1 = Enrollment::where(['school_id' => $school_id, 'year' => $sel_year, 'quarter' => 4, 'gender' => 0,'level'=>1])->first();
        $return .= "<tr>
                <td>Grade 1</td>
                <td>" . $male_q1_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $female_q1_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $male_q2_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $female_q2_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $male_q3_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $female_q3_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $male_q4_level1->value . "</td>
                <td>" . $female_q4_level1->value . "</td>
            </tr>";
        $return .= "</table>";

        return $return;
    }
```

Sample output.

[image]

As you can see, I made a single query for each of the data. How to make it simpler?
If there is no record in the database for a certain quarter, it should display zero (0).

Comment: You can maintain an array of quarter which furthur maintins level array. Then you can loop on that to get desired results easily.

Comment: can you try this https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby

Comment: `$collection->groupBy('meter_type');`